# when to pass a variable as an address in a function in php

Tags: php

I know what ampersand means in a function, it means you have to pass the variable by address. But i have not encountered a scenario wherein i need to pass some variable as an address. Can you  guys clarify this for me? like for example

```
function dollarx($x) {
    echo $x[1];
}

function dollar(&$x) {
    echo $x[1];
}

$x[0] = 1;
$x[1] = 2;
```

two functions displays the same

Comment: instead of `echo $x[1];` try `$x[1]=4;` then `var_dump($x);` before and after calling each function (its called pass-by-reference not address)

Comment: The difference comes if you `change` $x in your function, e.g. `echo $x[1]++;`

Comment: what does var_dump do?

Comment: dumps the contents of the variable explaining what each contains, including its type and size

Comment: you can also pass the variable back by reference too! http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass "by reference" when you want the function to be able to update the value of the variable.

For example:

```
function dollar(&$x){
    $x[1] = 12;
}

$x = array(1, 2);
dollar($x);

var_dump($x); // array(1, 12);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use it to have a function set variables for you. For example you could have a function return an array with results, or you could use variables by reference.

```
function GetUsernameAndEmailAddress(&$user, &$email) {
  //get values from database or session or whatever.

  $user = 'username';
  $email = 'email@example.com';
}


$username = '';
$email = '';
GetUsernameAndEmailAddress($username, $email);

echo 'Hello '. $username. '. I have sent an e-mail to '.$email;
```